# Disabling 'Dock as Tabbed document' in Avalandock

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

Presently we have a GUI developed, containing a customized layout using Avalondock 2.0. The layouts have a default context menu that is provided. However, I don't want to have the "Dock as Tabbed document" option.
I'd like to know if there's any way to remove or disable the option in the context menu.

I have come across posts which said I can customize the context menu but I don't want to create a customized context menu since that would make the code a lot more complicated.

Comment: Please clear your question. difficult to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite easy: just paste this snippet in your Docking Manager tag:

```
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.AnchorableContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Float" Command="{Binding Path=FloatCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Dock" Command="{Binding Path=DockCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Dock as Tabbed Document" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Auto Hide" Command="{Binding Path=AutoHideCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Hide" Command="{Binding Path=HideCommand}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Close" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.AnchorableContextMenu>
```

And you get rid of the command. No other coding or changes in your project are required.